# Reposition a button while onclick event

Tags: jsf, button, onclick, popupwindow

I can't reposition a button while clicking on calender component. I did some research but couldn't find a solution. My Problem is:
in my application there is a pop up window, that has input fields, a calender and two buttons (ok and cancel).problem that I am facing is, while clicking calender component two buttons are getting hide(ok and cancel button).I have to repostion these two buttons so that after I clicked the calender component the two buttons should still be visible.

```
<rich:calendar value="#{cancelContractBean.cancellationDate}" isDayEnabled="disablementFunction" dayStyleClass="disabledClassesProv"
popup="true" showApplyButton="false" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px">
  <goga:jodaLocalDateConverter />
  <a4j:support event="onclick" "change the button position" />
</rich:calendar>
```

Can someone guide me a way to achieve this?I have googled and did some experiments with calender component's onlick but still no success :(

Comment: Would you mind to create a jsfiddle example with generated HTML output?